# What is the meaning of the Mean output for Matlab's Expstat()?

Tags: statistics, matlab, wolfram-alpha, exponential-distribution

I'm having a hell of a time figuring out why Matlab disagrees with my hand calcs and Wolfram Alpha about the expectation of an exp(1/2) distribution.

By my hand calcs (which are pretty simple), and according to Wolfram, the expectation(mean) of an exp(1/2) is = 2. Makes sense.

However, in Matlab, whether I simulate the result or just use expstat(1/2), it keeps telling me that the mean is 0.5.

What does this mean?

Comment: There are two parametrizations of the exponential distribution, one by the rate (the reciprocal of the mean time) and another by the mean. The former has pdf $\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$, the latter has pdf $\frac{1}{\lambda} e^{-x/\lambda}$. I'm guessing Matlab's is using the latter.

Comment: Shouldn't I get a different value when I sum(x*pdf(x)), then? When I multiply the PDF vector in matlab by the input vector and sum it, I get roughly the same number. I even copied the input and PDF vectors from Matlab to Excel, multiplied and summed them there, and get the same number. I'm pretty confused.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. It seems to me that the point here is that $\int_0^\infty x 2e^{-2x} dx = 1/2$ and $\int_0^\infty x \frac{1}{2} e^{-x/2} dx = 2$.

Comment: Not sure about parameterization in Matlab. In R statistical software the code  `mean(rexp(10^6, 1/2)); mean(rexp(10^6, 2))` returns 2.000583 and
0.5002726, for simulations with rate 1/2 (mean 2) and rate 2 (mean 1/2), respectively.

Comment: @Ian: you were correct, Matlab is using a different parametrization than I was (see https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/exponential-distribution.html). I am using the former, mentioned in your first comment.